# Problems with loading of the jquery interface,

Tags: jquery

rather than relying on a CDN,..i dont want to use the internet connection to access the jquery interface,on my application for andriod, i want it to be off-line..pls can any one guide me on how to add the j query library to my app (i used html, java, css) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just download jQuery, add it to your project, then reference it in the HTML like this for example:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/theme-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min" />

<script src="_/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="_/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="_/js/myscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css" />

</head>
this are my codes

Comment: i tried transferring all the css files from the zip,to my css folder then linked it to the header and i transferred all the js files from the zip, on to my js folder then linked all to the header....but it would not load jquery mobile

Comment: When you say it would not load jQuery mobile, what do you mean? There are so many reasons it is not working. Have you used the jQuery mobile attributes on your HTML tags? Example: data-role="page" and data-role="header"?

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery Mobile documentation, it is real simple to get working: **http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/intro/**